# (C#) Given a circle, a set of angles, and the average of those angles: how do I find out how many degrees/radians are between them?

Tags: c#, xna, degrees, angle, radians

Chart 1:

[image: Diagram!]

So let's say I'm given angles 1,2,3, and 4 and their average.  Imagine that these angles could potentially be any angle on the circle.

How do I:

A. From the average angle, detect the furthest angle in the clockwise direction (4).

B. From the average angle, detect the furthest angle in the counterclockwise direction (1).

C. Compute the radians/degrees between A and B that INCLUDES the average angle in that range.  I'm not entirely sure how to phrase this, but going by the way the chart is setup, C should essentially be the difference in radians/degrees going clockwise from angle 1 until you reach angle 4.

Another example:

Chart 2:

[image: Chart 2]

A should be angle 1, B should be angle 2, and C should be 270 degrees (not 90).

Comment: Looks like a math question to me. Try http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: pseudocode `((((angle1 - angle2) mod 360) + 540) mod 360) - 180` return angle difference (-180...180) between angle1 and angle2 (in degrees)

Comment: @unlimit I'm specifically looking for this answer from a programmatic perspective.  Specifically C#.

Comment: @Dmi7ry That won't work.  While that does give you the difference between two angles, it will not give you the range that includes the overall average.  For example, on Chart 2 your code would return 90 degrees instead of 270.

Comment: just check this case. and for this modify result to 360-result

Comment: The majority of my question is how to check for this case...however, that does give me an idea about how to approach it.

Comment: Ok. Calculate the difference between each angle and the average value. Sum of modules of biggest of them is the value C.